# Excel scatter chart: go from marker to data point cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I need to be able to go from marker on a scatter chart to the cell of the data point of this marker. Is there any way to do that?

I see I can get to display data point values in a tooltip if I hover mouse pointer above the marker, but it doesn't show data cell coordinates: [scatter chart marker tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plLb6.png)

Clicking on marker does not lead to the data cell, and there is nothing helpful in the marker's context menu.

Comment: I am a porter now. According to [the thread in Chinese](http://club.excelhome.net/thread-562167-1-1.html), you may achieve it via VBA. Please refer to the first sample “Chart7" of “8th floor”. I added a "Scatter" sheet in [this sample](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnHoiCikfd80iAgKCWt7fJueumgR?e=30rpyZ) for a test. (Please note, Excel online does not support VBA.)

Comment: Thank you, @Emily, looks like exactly what I need. Would give your comment +1 if I could.